# Cannot access translation of a variable attribute name in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm having a hard time getting an attribute translated in Angular.

I'm ng-repeating on an array in which every item have a 'day' attribute.

```
<h2 ng-repeat="f in forecast">{{ "days[f.day]" | translate }} {{ f.date | date:'dd' }}</h2>
```

On the translation part I have a 'days' attribute which has 7 children attributes, one for each day of the week.

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
  ...
  days: {
    sunday:'Sunday',
    monday:'Monday',
    tuesday:'Tuesday',
    wednesday:'Wednesday',
    thursday:'Thursday',
    friday:'Friday',
    saturday:'Saturday'
  }
});
```

So I'm trying to access the right translation in the 'days' attribute with the 'f.day' value, but I'm cannot find the right syntax.

I would gladly appreciate some help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: it would be cool if you create a jsfiddle. so we can understand better

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see wrong with what you have provided is how you have set up `days` in your provider.

What you have is basically an associative array:

```
days: {
    sunday:'Sunday',
    monday:'Monday',
    tuesday:'Tuesday',
    wednesday:'Wednesday',
    thursday:'Thursday',
    friday:'Friday',
    saturday:'Saturday'
}
```

With this current structure you can't do stuff like `days[f.day]` unless you know for sure that `f.day` will match one of your keys. An example would be something like `days.friday`

So the first thing to check would be to log `f.day` to see what it actually is.

This following suggestion is based on the assumption that `f.day` is an integer. In order for `days[f.day]` to work you want days to be an array like this:

```
days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
]
```

You could also do an array of objects like this:

```
days = [
    {"name":"Sunday"},
    {"name":"Monday"},
    {"name":"Tuesday"},
    {"name":"Wednesday"},
    {"name":"Thursday"},
    {"name":"Friday"},
    {"name":"Saturday"},
]
```

But then you would have to do `days[f.day].name` (again assuming f.day is an integer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response Chris, I get the days right...but the problem is when I put it in between brackets with the translater filter. Like this:

```
{{ "days[f.day]" | translate }}
```

Inside my view it show: **days[f.day]** and not the translation.

Comment: Well I think I found a way to achieve this.

It's not the same example, but it's a concatenation with a model value.

{{ 'home.' + button.label | translate }}